# Get multiple from Xmldocument

Tags: c#, xpath, xml-parsing

i query and get this information from another source

```
<queryResult xmlns="http://apiblah">
<template>
<entity name="Nodes" type="apiblah" dynamic="False">
<property name="NodeID" type="Int32" /> 
</entity>
</template>
<data>
<Nodes>
<NodeID>823</NodeID> 
</Nodes>
<Nodes>
<NodeID>825</NodeID> 
</Nodes>
<Nodes>
<NodeID>826</NodeID> 
</Nodes>
<Nodes>
<NodeID>839</NodeID> 
</Nodes>
<Nodes>
<NodeID>935</NodeID> 
</Nodes>
</data>
</queryResult>
```

i'm trying to extract all the nodeIDs from this kind of an XML and i'm unable to get all of them into an array.

Everytime i try to go through , i only get the first NodeID

```
var nodeID = result.XPathSelectElement("//*[local-name()='NodeID']").Value; is what works for the first nodeid
```

Any suggestions on how i can get all of them as an array? 
The multiple NodeID tags are putting my code off

Comment: You can only get XML Elements from XPath queries that return multiples.   So once you get a list of nodes, you'll have to iterate over the list to extract the values and put them in an array.

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to switch to XDocument (System.Linq.Xml), then you could do:

```
    string xml = @"<queryResult xmlns=""http://apiblah"">
<template>
<entity name=""Nodes"" type=""apiblah"" dynamic=""False"">
<property name=""NodeID"" type=""Int32"" /> 
</entity>
</template>
<data>
<Nodes>
<NodeID>823</NodeID> 
</Nodes>
<Nodes>
<NodeID>825</NodeID> 
</Nodes>
<Nodes>
<NodeID>826</NodeID> 
</Nodes>
<Nodes>
<NodeID>839</NodeID> 
</Nodes>
<Nodes>
<NodeID>935</NodeID> 
</Nodes>
</data>
</queryResult>";

XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
XNamespace ns = "http://apiblah";
var nodeids = doc.Descendants().Elements(ns + "NodeID");
foreach (var element in nodeids)
{
    Console.WriteLine(element.Value);
}
```

yields:

```
823
825
826
839
935
```